# TaskCanceledException after closing window

Tags: c#, wpf

So first of all, I have multiple windows which I hide when opening another window, so I have to use

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

to completely close the Application when pressing the "x" on the top right.

I wanted to handle the WindowClosing Event in my Home.xaml.cs file. But if I do this:

```cs
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Closing += WindowClosing.OnWindowClosing;
}
```

then I am getting an `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` when I am closing the window.

Here is the `WindowClosing` event handler:

```
public static void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

The weird part is, that I´ve done exactly the same with the login window, and it works there without any trouble.

I´ve stepped through it, and the closing event gets set as it should (in the Login.xaml.cs, as also in the Home.xaml.cs File).

I know this is not much Information for this error (I think thats all, but maybe the error is coming from somewhere else?!), but maybe someone else encountered this issue and can help me.
If you need more information just tell me, I will edit the question then.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

The Solution was taking `Environment.Exit(0);` instead of `Application.Current.Shutdown();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `OnWindowClosing()` method, you can try substituting the following line for `Application.Current.Shutdown()`:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: Environment.Exit(0); is working perfectly, thanks for that! But with Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown(); I am still getting the System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException.

Comment: See my edit, I got rid of the latter. Please upvote and accept as the correct answer!

Comment: Done it. Again, thanks for your fast response and help!